# правильная передача массива в $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, сессия

столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Есть база данных. Есть вывод названий таблиц из этой бд через цикл while и простой запрос. Вывод служит "меню-аккордеоном" в котором содержатся данные из таблиц бд(фото прилагается). Среди данных таблицы есть форма, состоящая из 2 кнопок (ДОБАВИТЬ ФЛАГ, УБРАТЬ ФЛАГ(см.фото)). Каждая форма имеет индивидуальный идентификатор, в зависимости от названия таблицы где находится. Форма передает данные на обработчик. Так как, для того чтобы название таблицы(которое записано в переменную) было видно в файле обработчика, я внес ту переменную в сессию. Но в обработчике видна лишь сессия с последней таблицей. ЛОГИЧНО. Вопрос: КАК ГРАМОТНО ПЕРЕДАТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ С НАЗВАНИЕМ ТАБЛИЦЫ В ДРУГОЙ ФАЙЛ ЧЕРЕЗ ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ?.
Фото и скрипты прилагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php 
require_once 'DEV/dbh_oa.php'; //Подключение к бд Абонентского отдела
$sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$dBName);  //Запрос на вывод названий таблиц из бд
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($sqli)) { // массив с данными
$_SESSION["name_table_oa"] = $rows[0]; //Для передачи названия таблицы в файл обработчика
echo '<ul>
                                                                    <form action="/addFlag.php" method="POST" class="forms_flag">
                                                                    <button class="btn_flag" type="submit" name="okk-set-flag-'.$_SESSION["name_table_oa"].'">Добавить флаг</button>
                                                                    <button class="btn_flag" type="submit" name="okk-del-flag-'.$_SESSION["name_table_oa"].'">Убрать флаг</button>
                                                                    </form>
                                                                    </ul>';

    }
?>
```

файл ОБРАБОТЧИКА

```
    <?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["okk-set-flag-".$_SESSION['name_table_oa'].""]) || isset($_POST["okk-del-flag-".$_SESSION['name_table_oa'].""])) {
    require_once 'DEV/dbh_oa.php';
    $name_oa = $_SESSION['name_table_oa'];

    if (isset($_POST["okk-set-flag-".$name_oa.""])) {

        $sql = "UPDATE `$name_oa` SET `flag` = '1' WHERE `$name_oa`.`clerk_id`";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($result == true) {
            header("Location: /index.php"); 
            exit();
        }
    }elseif (isset($_POST["okk-del-flag-".$name_oa.""])) {

        $sql = "UPDATE `$name_oa` SET `flag` = '0' WHERE `$name_oa`.`clerk_id`";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($result == true) {
            header("Location: /index.php"); 
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Передавать название таблицы вместе с другими данными формы.

Comment: @u_mulder Вся форма это 2 кнопки, название таблицы - переменная $rows[0]. NAME кнопки содержит индивидуальный идентификатор через $_SESSION. Я, чесно говоря, не совсем понимаю, каким образом это передать. можете подсказать детальнее?

Comment: Кстати, у вас очень странно выглядит update. Вы понимаете, что вы измените _ВСЕ_ записи в таблице, у которых не нулевой clerk_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="/addFlag.php" method="POST" class="forms_flag">
    <button class="btn_flag" type="submit" name="add"value>Добавить флаг</button>
    <button class="btn_flag" type="submit" name="del">Убрать флаг</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="table" value="tableName" />
</form>

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    echo 'Add to ' . $_POST['table'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['del'])) {
    echo 'Delete from ' . $_POST['table'];
}
```

Comment: Боже, как все просто. Какого лешего я вообще так далеко полез?))))
Спасибо за ответ. Прошу прощения за тупой вопрос)

Comment: Только не забывайте что данные с формы можно подделать и в поле `table` прислать имя таблицы, данные которой вы не хотите раскрывать.

Comment: @ЮрийГалай На самом деле все еще проще, я бы даже hidden поля не делал `<button class="btn_flag" type="submit" name="okk-flag" value="del:tableName">` (у второй кнопки name тот же, `value="set:tableName"`) при этом на входе у вас будет `$_POST['okk-flag']`, если он есть то делаем `list($action, $table) = explode(':', $_POST['okk-flag']);` у нас теперь на руках `$action` равный set или del и название таблицы. пишем всего один update в котором flag зависит от $action. Хотя можно и input имя таблицы отдать, а кнопки c value set или del